# Is there a way to publish a webjob on azure with a different target framework than the publish project?

Tags: azure, webjob

I have an azure web application in which I want to update a webjob project to target framework .net 7 but leave the web site at .net 4.7.1 due to legacy constraints on the project.

Is it possible to deploy webjobs with different target frameworks than the web site? If not, is there a better way to approach this problem?

I tried updating the webjob project to .net 7 and deploying, but I the following error when I deploy a webjob to azure that has a different target framework (.net 7.0) than the website (4.7.1).

> [12/12/2023 01:07:43 > 0f00b5: ERR ] You must install or update .NET to run this application.
> [12/12/2023 01:07:43 > 0f00b5: ERR ]
> [12/12/2023 01:07:43 > 0f00b5: ERR ] App: C:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\WebJobs\2vgixjvc.b00\WebJobs.exe
> [12/12/2023 01:07:43 > 0f00b5: ERR ] Architecture: x64
> [12/12/2023 01:07:43 > 0f00b5: ERR ] Framework: 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '7.0.0' (x64)
> [12/12/2023 01:07:43 > 0f00b5: ERR ] .NET location: C:\Program Files\dotnet

Changing the Web App configuration to .net 7 does not seem to make a difference.

Webjob project file as requested:
[image: Webjob Project File]

Webjob program.cs
[image: Program.cs for webjob]

Comment: So you want to publish .net framework 4.7.1 to .net core 7 app?

Comment: Please share your `.csproj` file.

Comment: Also share your program.cs code file.

Comment: Specifically, I am trying to publish a .net 7 webjob to an azure app service that is configured to .net 7, but the primary web application's targetframework is .net 4.7.1.  The web application publishes fine, but the webjobs gives the error `You must install or update .NET to run this application.`

Comment: Do you have any other code for functions in another file?

Comment: Instead of image post your code as text format.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to deploy webjobs with different target frameworks than the web site?

If you want to deploy to any other Version of .NET other than the existing website,
Follow the below steps.

- Create an Azure App Service with .NET 7.

[image]

- From Visual Studio, Publish to Web Job
  [image]
  select the already created App Service (with .NET7 Core version) and deploy the app.
  [image]

> You must install or update .NET to run this application.

If you get this error with Framework website hosted in .Net Core,try to install the `ASP.NET Core 7.0 Runtime extension.

[image]

As per this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs),

> The way that you deploy a WebJobs project is different for .NET Core projects than for .NET Framework projects.

> I tried updating the webjob project to .net 7 and deploying

Migrating from .NET Framework to .NET Core requires manual work.

- `.Net Core` requires `appsettings.json` file to add the Connection String (related to WebJob).In `.Net Framework` app your connection strings are stored in `App.config` file.
- Even `.csproj` in framework app contains additional settings which are not required for Core Apps, even those have to be edited.
- AFAIK,It is better to create a separate Core Application and add the existing Functions/Jobs to it.

### Update

- For .NET Framework Applications, Publish as Azure Web Job can be seen just below the Publish option.

[image]

- Whereas in Console .NET 7 Core app, the option is available under

`Publish` => `Add a publish profile`=> `Azure` => `Azure WebJobs`

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! I will give it a try soon

Comment: I tried for a couple hours lots of variations on making this work, but I am giving up and reverting the newer project to 4.7.1. Seems like no matter what I do I don't get the "publish as azure webjob" option for .net7, even in a new solution for a blank console app

Comment: Publish as Web Job Option can be seen in the `Publish` => `Azure` => `Azure Web Jobs` for .Net7 Console App.Please check the update section in the answer.